# Custom Progress List LWC does not render correctly due to additional HTML tags

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds

I am trying to create a [custom progress list](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/setup-assistant/) LWC, which should look like this:

[image]

The parent component is structured like this:

```
<template>
    <ol class="slds-progress__list slds-progress__list-bordered">
        <slot></slot>
    </ol>
</template>
```

And the child component is structured like this:

```
<template>
    <li class="slds-progress__item">
        <div class="slds-progress__marker"></div>
        <div class="slds-progress__item_content slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread">
            <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">{description}</div>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-end slds-size_1-of-2">
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</template>
```

Which has a JavaScript:

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

export default class ProgressListItem extends LightningElement {
    @api description;
}
```

When used together:

```
<template>
    <c-progress-list>
        <c-progress-list-item description="text on left">text on right</c-progress-list-item>
        <c-progress-list-item description="text on left">text on right</c-progress-list-item>
        <c-progress-list-item description="text on left">text on right</c-progress-list-item>
    </c-progress-list>
</template>
```

But the component still does not render correctly:

[image]

But when it renders is adds additional HTML tags, which alter the structure, stopping the CSS from working correctly

```
<ol class="slds-progress__list slds-progress__list-bordered">
     <slot>
         <c-progress-list-item> 
             <li class="slds-progress__item">
                 ...
             </li>
         </c-progress-list-item>
     </slot>
</ol>
```

I've tried adding some CSS to make the tags become invisible from a structure perspective:

```
slot {
    display: contents;
}

c-progress-list-item {
    display: contents;
}
```

But the component still does not render correctly.

What can I do to get it to render correctly?